# List view item having multiple buttons

Tags: android, listview

My list view item has 3 or 4 buttons and I am calling a web service with each button, which I am doing by using asynch task, now my questions is that I want to show button clicked by changing  background of button according to the result of web service call.

Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

1. Pass the reference of the button you clicked(view Obtained
   from its onClickListener) to the asyncTask you are about to execute
2. Start the asyncTask
3. In the Post execute, change the background of the view.

Comment: do i need to add notifydatasetchanged() method in onPostExecute() method?

Comment: b'coz somewhere on stackoverflow i have seen that you need to call notifydatasetchanged() to make things visible in list view.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869895/listview-update-after-complete-asynctask

Comment: You have to call notifydatasetchanged() which will internally call onLayout() to modify your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the changes to your button's setBacgroundColor() method in the onPostExecute() method in the AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
             //Do what ever you want depending on the result that you 
             //you pass in the return of the doInBackGround....
             button.setBackGroundColor(Color.GREEN);
     }
```